# Using jQuery how can we remove disabled attribute from all elements whose value is false?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, dom-manipulation

I have input checkboxes printed like the following.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="a1" value="11" disabled="false">
<input type="checkbox" id="a2" value="21" disabled="true">
<input type="checkbox" id="a3" value="31" disabled="false">
```

I know the disabled attribute takes no value. So when the attribute is present the element becomes disabled irrespective of the value assigned to it. I want to remove all the disabled attribute from all input elements whose value is false.

Using jQuery I would like to use code like the following.

```
$("*[disabled]").not(true).removeAttr("disabled");
```

Comment: Something to note: once this is removed, AFAIK, it cannot be put back.

Comment: But why would you want to do this?

Comment: Exactly... why even do this?

Comment: Fix the problem at source. Don't deliver the broken HTML to the client in the first place.

Comment: I am using a cloud based development framework where I cannot print attribute in an element with no value. So I am going to use jQuery to remove the one with false value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you just match elements where `disabled` is `false`?

```
$('[disabled="false"]​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​')​.removeAttr('disabled');​​​
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ASN29/**

The presence of the `disabled` attribute automatically makes the element disabled, regardless of the attribute's value, so this isn't a very good idea. How does the HTML become this way?

Comment: In Salesforce.com cloud environment the widget(component) that prints the html element, every attribute must have a value just like XML attribute.

Comment: Mine has this problem because firefox cached the results of filling a dropdown. Some of the dropdown elements were disabled from the previous use of the page, and firefox loaded from cache with the disabled attributes still there. On page load, I want to remove ALL disabled attributes.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply use a selector like this:

```
$('input[disabled="false"]').removeAttr("disabled");
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/amTpv/)

Instead of `*`, I added `input`, it narrows the query down a lot. This will search for `input` elements that have an attribute called `disabled` having the value `false`.

I would suggest you don't do this at all. That HTML should have never been generated.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to enabled them use the [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop) instead .. (*that is because `disabled` as an actual property of `checkbox` inputs*)

```
$('input[disabled="false"]').prop('disabled', false);
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/Bn4dr/

---

The correct way, though, would be to print the proper *html* directly

```
<input type="checkbox" id="a1" value="11">
<input type="checkbox" id="a2" value="21" disabled>
<input type="checkbox" id="a3" value="31">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
​$(document).ready(function (){
    $('input:disabled').removeAttr('disabled');    
});​
```

Here is the [jsFiddle for it](http://jsfiddle.net/6W2cv/) and documentation on [:disabled selector](http://api.jquery.com/disabled-selector/)

Comment: The presence of the `disabled` attribute automatically makes the element disabled, regardless of the attribute's value, so this will remove the `disabled` attribute from *all* elements with the `disabled` attribute.

Comment: Works for enabling all disabled elements

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[disabled="false"]').removeAttr("disabled");
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/JKs4C/

As to whether this is a good idea, on the other hand... I think the real answer is to fix up your server-side rendering to omit the disabled attribute entirely for elements that aren't disabled. Otherwise you'll end up with all elements disabled if your scripts go wrong, noscript, etc.